# Finding vowels occupy places in word?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From the different words formed out of the letters in the world allahabad the number of words in which the vowels occupy the even places are ?

My Try :

$\frac{9!}{4!\times2!}=15120$

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a l l a h a b a d
```

I found only one vowel which is `A` at the position `4,6,8`

How i can can apply conditions which is said in problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your words are of the form:

```
_ a _ a _ a _ a _
```

so you only have to choose 5 letters so the number of possibilities is $\frac{5!}{2!}=60$

Comment: Okay , i understood .. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you devide by $2!$?

Comment: @rbm because we have 2 $\ell$

Comment: @metacompactness What exactly does '$2l$' mean? Could you be more specific? Don't we only have to order the 5 letters?

Comment: @rbm We have to choose 5 letters from $\{l;l;h;;b;d\}$ but we have 2 identical letters in this set.

Comment: @metacompactness Ah, I didn't notice that the $l$ appears twice. Thanks!